# Getting the value of the first object in dataset on a HTML DOM with javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have a DOM like this:

```
<div data-info="{"partnerLink":"https://bing.com","fillColor":"rgba(10,91,144,1)"}"></div>
```

Is there any way to get the value of partnerLink (in this case https://bing.com) in JS?

I know it would be better to have data-partnerLink and data-fillColor but this is what I have for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to fix your quotes like so:

```
<div data-info='{"partnerLink":"https://bing.com","fillColor":"rgba(10,91,144,1)"}'></div>
```

(All I changed were the very first and last `""` into `''` so it wouldn't interfere with the inner quotes).

And you can do it like this:

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div"); //Add an ID and use getElementById if there's more than one div
var partnerLink = JSON.parse(div.getAttribute("data-info")).partnerLink;
console.log(partnerLink);
```

```html
<div data-info='{"partnerLink":"https://bing.com","fillColor":"rgba(10,91,144,1)"}'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Fix the object. The quotes you are using are wrong. Access the element using querySelector and get the attributes using getAttribute. Using dot notation print the object property

```js
var a=document.querySelector('div')
var b=a.getAttribute('data-info');
console.log(JSON.parse(b).partnerLink)
```

```html
<div data-info='{"partnerLink":"https://bing.com","fillColor":"rgba(10,91,144,1)"}'></div>
```